# missing TfxInstaller task for YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the [Add a custom pipelines task extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops) Microsoft describe how to create a custom Azure DevOps task extension. Under [Step 6: Create a build and release pipeline to publish the extension to Marketplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops#step-6-create-a-build-and-release-pipeline-to-publish-the-extension-to-marketplace) they show a example of YAML pipeline which should automatically build and publish your custom extension to the marketplace.

The last stage of the YAML pipeline:

```
 - stage: Download_build_artifacts_and_publish_the_extension
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - task: TfxInstaller@3
            inputs:
              version: "v0.7.x"
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: "current"
              downloadType: "single"
              artifactName: "$(ArtifactName)"
              downloadPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
          - task: PublishAzureDevOpsExtension@3
            inputs:
              connectTo: 'VsTeam'
              connectedServiceName: 'ServiceConnection' # Change to whatever you named the service connection
              fileType: 'vsix'
              vsixFile: '/Publisher.*.vsix'
              publisherId: '$(PublisherID)'
              extensionId: '$(ExtensionID)'
              extensionName: '$(ExtensionName)'
              updateTasksVersion: false
              extensionVisibility: 'private' # Change to public if you're publishing to the marketplace
              extensionPricing: 'free'
```

contains the tasks `TfxInstaller` and `PublishAzureDevOpsExtension`.

On our **Azure DevOps 2019.1 (on premise)** server I get the feedback that these tasks are **unknown**. Also when I try to seek for more information's about this tasks, I do not found anything. Not in the docs, not on the marketplace and not on google.

Where can I find these tasks Microsoft using for there tutorials? Any more information's about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install  [Azure DevOps Extension Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-developer-tools-build-tasks&ssr=false#overview)  in order to use `TfxInstaller` and `PublishAzureDevOpsExtension`.

Comment: Damnit, now I see it in the *Prerequisites*. Such a shame :(. Thank you for that answer!